# Display the fields of the current taxonomy with an exposed form

Tags: 8, views, taxonomy-terms

I'm using the Taxonomy term view.

I expose the "Has taxonomy term" filter to my users in a block.

I want to display the title and the fields of the current taxonomy even when a term has been typed in the exposed form.

However, apparently, when the view is filtered, views no longer finds the argument in the url since the url contains an `all?tid=`.

Do you know how to do it ?

**For example:**

I have a tag "Tag 1", with a description "Description Tag 1".

If I go to the `mysite.com/tags/tag-1` page, it works, I come up with the replacement patterns to get what I want.

But, when I filter the view with the exposed form, I get url `mysite.com/taxonomy/term/all?tid=tag+1`, and the replacement patterns no longer work. For "%1", I get "all". For other tokens, I got errors.

Comment: You should have the ID number of the term in the URL after using the exposed filter unless you're using Ajax then you won't see anything extra in the URL. There is a difference in what you see after the `?` depending on what you chose in the Filter settings. But it shouldn't be empty, maybe there is a bug on your site? Try checking again, or provide more info in your question about your settings.

Comment: @prkos I edited my question with an example.

Comment: "Has taxonomy term" filter uses term IDs, not term Names. Try with TID. Why do you need both Contextual and regular term filter?

Comment: @prkos My view is the default taxonomy view. She obviously uses the TID. I think the exposed filter is used to choose with which tag the content is filtered, and the contextual filter is used to display information on the chosen tag